# Prototype select last input

Tags: prototypejs

```
<form id="file_upload_form"> ...
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

Just need a alert box to appear on clicking the input.  I'm a jQuery man so not sure how to target the DOM with prototype.  I can't edit the HTML otherwise I would just give it an ID.

Must be easy but can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$$('#file_upload_form > input[type="submit"]').first().observe('click', 
    function() 
    { 
        alert('Hello'); 
    });
```

`$$` is Prototype's Selector engine shortcut. You can use any CSS selector to pick up the elements you are interested in. `first()` just grabs the first element returned, and `observe()` is the standard way to subscribe to events in Prototype.

Edit: Wrong quote marks